# How do I rename the tabs in the Kendo UI spreadsheet?

Tags: html, kendo-ui, telerik

In the Kendo UI spreadsheet (sorting and filtering) component there are 3 tabs reading 'Home/Insert/Data'. In the html there is no reference to the tabs. How do I re-name those?

[Here is a link to the component](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/sorting-filtering) in the Demos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tabs is actually what is called as Spreadsheet Toolbar. Home/Insert/Data are all different actions you do on the sheet itself. at the moment there is no hook to rename them ...

Comment: Thanks! I had to figure out a work-around to get tabs with my own labels on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can always play with the html. Check http://dojo.telerik.com/@uygard/IXEgo

Comment: Thanks for answering; it was helpful to review your sample. Have a great day.